# Cognos, modifying canned report. Namespace of tag doesn't exist

Tags: cognos

I want to modify a canned report to add more information to what it already provides. However, when I go to one of the data items, to see where it originates from so that I can know where to add my own data item from, I don't understand the expression given.

For instance, the finished Query has a data item `Patients Name`. Here is the expression for Patients name:`[NO Group No Resource].[CPT With OUT Resource Proivder No Groups].[Patient Name]`

However, there is no namespace`[NO Group No Resource]`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think the reason for this was because the entire thing was written in sql. Some of the reports provided for us do not use the Data Items given to us, they are just written in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm copying the comment I made above here so that I can set this question as 'Answered'.

**I think the reason for this was because the entire thing was written in sql. Some of the reports provided for us do not use the Data Items given to us, they are just written in SQL**